# Angularjs: set Authorization on http request header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

in Angularjs i have a login page and if a user succesfully sign in i set the Authorization attribute as default on subsequent http request header:

```
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + data.access_token;
```

So, anytime i make a request, in the header is present the Authorization parameter and all works.
The problem is that if i refresh the page, in the header request isn't present the Authorization parameter and the request fail.

Why isn't present the Authorization parameter if i set it as default in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page all the javascript memory data are gone. You will need to store the bearer token in the browser local storage and get it back from the localstorage and again set it in your common header on page reload.

[You can check the localstorage working here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)